# Java: Reasonable timeout period for URLConnection

Tags: java, url, timeout

By default the timeout for URLConnection is 0 which is unlimited.  What is a reasonable value for XXXXX?

```
URL url = ...
URLConnection uCon = url.openConnection();
uCon.setConnectTimeout(XXXXXX);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything is reasonable. Depending on the latency, on the target page. etc. Let's say 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on your business logic. How long do you want your program to wait before it decides that it will just give up, rather than wait?

("Maybe if I just wait a *little* longer, then it'll connect!")