# What timeout set for apache http client?

Tags: android, apache-commons-httpclient, connection-timeout

I'm using apache http client

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
//...
my_httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(my_httpParams, 300);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(my_httpParams, 300);
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(my_httpParams);
```

for fetching name matching calling number from services like http://klicktel.de/ (reverse number lookup, using in Android Call Log for example). As you can see I set timeout to 300ms for both connection and socket timeout.

**Do you have any hints what timeout should be set to be reasonable?** I mean: user want to see the reversed-number but on the other hand user don't want to wait indefinitely for the number to be fetched.

Comment: You should avoid questions that ask for vague things, as in, things that don't have an objective answer. Things you shouldn't ask:
- What do you recommend,
- What do you think,
- Any hints on,

Take a look at the guidelines:

http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) which seems to answer my question:

> Implementation of the Apache DefaultHttpClient that is configured with reasonable default settings and registered schemes for Android

Answer (score 0):

You can give any value I usually give 15 seconds.You can give any value

Comment: The question is asking how long should be the time out, not the measurement to be used.

Comment: My bad .What i meant was to give an extreme limit as 15 secs n 10 secs respectively

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972345/java-reasonable-timeout-period-for-urlconnection Check whether this helps

Comment: Fix your answer and I'll remove the downvote. 
Another thing is, do you really want to leave your user hanging on for 15 seconds before saying anything? In my opinion 1 to 3 secs is the best balance.

Comment: Actually I don't even think this is a valid SO question cause it's not asking for something that can be answered objectively.

Comment: Answer edited.Ya i know its kind of high value.the reason why i give such a  large value  is when it comes to slow speed internet connection i think it might help not  to disconnect.I could be wrong.Still i prefer that